# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string (Return the last day of month)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR = '201809';  


-- Month and Year

DECLARE @mes VARCHAR(2), @ano VARCHAR(4)
SET @mes = SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 6)   
SET @ano = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)

--Return last day of Month

SELECT DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@ano + @mes + '01'))))
```

Comment: SELECT DAY(EOMONTH('201809'+'01')) --is enough to get last day of month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't declare the size for the varchar for `@date`. So basically @date only contains the character `2`

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(6) = '201809';  


-- Month and Year

DECLARE @mes VARCHAR(2), @ano VARCHAR(4)
SET @mes = SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 6)   
SET @ano = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)

--Return last day of Month

SELECT DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@ano + @mes + '01'))))
```

if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can simply

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(6) = '201809';  
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, @date + '01', 112)))
```

Comment: I don't see the point in `@ano` and `@mes`, but +1 to your good catch.

Comment: Might be worth adding this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Version 2012 or higher, you can use the built in `EOMonth` function to get the last date of the month.

Also, please note (as also mentioned in Squirrel's answer) that you didn't specify the length of the `varchar` when declaring the `@Date` variable - This means that SQL Server will create it as `varchar(1)` and truncate the value to `2`.

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(6) = '201809';

SELECT EOMONTH(@date + '01')
```

Please note that `yyyymmdd` format is the alternative ISO8601 format, meaning that SQL Server can implicitly convert a string representation of `date` values in this format to `Date` and will always do it correctly regardless of local settings or even explicitly setting `dateformat` to any other value (`dmy`, `mdy` etc')

Answer (score 1):

Its working please try this

```
DECLARE @date CHAR(10) = '201809';  


-- Month and Year

DECLARE @mes VARCHAR(2), @ano VARCHAR(4)    SET @mes = SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 6)   SET @ano = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)

--Return last day of Month

SELECT DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@ano + @mes + '01'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should declare varchar(6)

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(6) = '201809';  

-- Month and Year
select @date
DECLARE @mes VARCHAR(2), @ano VARCHAR(4)
SET @mes = SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 6)   
SET @ano = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)
select @mes,@ano

--Return last day of Month
SELECT DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@ano + @mes + '01'))))
```

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9UwR.png): you should declare varchar(6)

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(6) = '201809';  

-- Month and Year
select @date
DECLARE @mes VARCHAR(2), @ano VARCHAR(4)
SET @mes = SUBSTRING(@date, 5, 6)   
SET @ano = SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 4)
select @mes,@ano

--Return last day of Month
SELECT DAY(DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(M,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@ano + @mes + '01'))))
```

[Screen shot][0]

Answer (score 0):

From SQL 2012 you can use EOMonth

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SELECT EOMONTH (@currentDate) AS LastDayOfMonth
```